# Bukkit Development - Doesn't Remove Item In Hand on Sign Interact

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Basically I am trying to have a kit system where the player gets items from a defined kit in the config and which pulls in fine first time, but if the user then wants to change the kit, the item that the user currently holds remains the same as it changes all the other items.

The onSignInteract event:

```
@EventHandler
public void onSignInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e)
{
    Player player = e.getPlayer();

    if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK))
    {
        Block block = e.getClickedBlock();

        if (block.getType() == Material.SIGN || block.getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN)
        {
            Sign sign = (Sign)block.getState();

            String[] line = sign.getLines();

            if (line[0].equalsIgnoreCase("[C KIT]"))
            {               
                for (String kit : Main.kits)
                {
                    if (line[1].equalsIgnoreCase(kit)) // The power is strong with this one
                    {
                        //for testing purposes
                        Main.logger.info("BEFORE CLEAR: " + player.getInventory().getItemInHand().toString());

                        clearInv(player);
                        e.getPlayer().setItemInHand(null);
                        // for testing purposes
                        Main.logger.info("AFTER CLEAR: " + player.getInventory().getItemInHand().toString());

                        List<String> ids = Main.config.getStringList("kits." + kit);

                        for (String id : ids)
                        {
                            // ItemSlot-ItemID-Amount-Enchantments(comma separate)-PotionDetails
                            String[] split = id.split("-");
                            ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Main.getMaterialById(Integer.parseInt(split[1])), Integer.parseInt(split[2]));

                            if (split[1].equals(String.valueOf(373)))
                            {
                                String[] potDet = split[4].split("\\.");

                                String potType = potDet[0];
                                String potName = potDet[1];
                                String potLvl;

                                if (potDet.length == 3)
                                {
                                    potLvl = potDet[2];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    potLvl = "1";
                                }

                                boolean splash;

                                if (potType.equals("sp"))
                                {
                                    splash = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    splash = false;
                                }

                                int potLevel = Integer.parseInt(potLvl);

                                Potion potion = new Potion(Main.getPotion(potName));

                                potion.setSplash(splash);
                                potion.setLevel(potLevel);
                                item = potion.toItemStack(Integer.parseInt(split[2]));

                                player.getInventory().addItem(item);
                            }
                            else if (!split[3].equals(null) && !split[3].equalsIgnoreCase("") && !split[3].equalsIgnoreCase("0.0"))
                            {
                                item = new ItemStack(Main.getMaterialById(Integer.parseInt(split[1])), Integer.parseInt(split[2]));

                                String[] enchants = split[3].split(",");

                                for (String s : enchants)
                                {
                                    String[] enchant = s.split("\\.");

                                    int level = Integer.parseInt(enchant[1]);
                                    Enchantment en = Main.getEnchantment(enchant[0]);

                                    if (en != null)
                                    {
                                        item.addEnchantment(en, level);
                                    }
                                }

                                // Check for Armour
                                if (split[0].equals(String.valueOf(103)))
                                {
                                    player.getInventory().setHelmet(item);
                                }
                                else if (split[0].equals(String.valueOf(102)))
                                {
                                    player.getInventory().setChestplate(item);
                                }
                                else if (split[0].equals(String.valueOf(101)))
                                {
                                    player.getInventory().setLeggings(item);
                                }
                                else if (split[0].equals(String.valueOf(100)))
                                {
                                    player.getInventory().setBoots(item);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    player.getInventory().addItem(item);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                player.getInventory().addItem(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

clearInv(Player player) method:

```
public static void clearInv(Player p)
{
    PlayerInventory pi = p.getInventory();

    p.setHealth(20.0);
    p.setFoodLevel(20);
    pi.clear();
    pi.setArmorContents(null);
    p.getItemInHand().setType(Material.AIR);

    for (PotionEffect effect : p.getActivePotionEffects())
    {
        p.removePotionEffect(effect.getType());
    }       
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `p.getItemInHand().setType(Material.AIR);` all together, `p.getInventory().clear();` will clear everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p.getItemInHand().setType(Material.AIR);
```

This changes the `Material` of the `Item` object, it doesn't actually remove the item itself. To clear the item in use, simply use:

```
p.setItemInHand(null);
```